# Finding all combinations of longs with certain bits set

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, poker

This is such an obscure problem that I suspect I'll have to do it at a different level in my code...but hopefully the hive mind that is Stack Overflow can help...

I have a long, which if expressed as a binary string will have exactly five bits set. For example,

```
long l = 341; // as a bit string, "101010101"
```

I'm seeking an array containing all ten possible longs which exactly three of those bits set. To continue the example,

```
long[] results = {
  101010000,
  101000100,
  101000001,
  100010100,
  100010001,
  100000101,
    1010100,
    1010001,
    1000101,
      10101
}
```

Here's what the appropriate method signature might look like:

```
public long[] toThreeBitCombinations(long l) {
    // what goes here?
}
```

(The problem domain is poker; enumerating all the possible board card combinations in a Omaha Poker hand. Yep, there are other ways to approach this, but I am testing out this approach, as dealing with bits is so much quicker than most other alternatives.)

Comment: Note that an integer literal that begins with a `0` is considered octal.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis good point...thanks

Comment: Also, `Long` has a `bitCount` method that `Returns the number of one-bits in the two's complement binary representation of the specified long value.`

Comment: Surely there are loads of existing questions on SO about combination generation?  Are they not applicable here?

Comment: It can be done using a [`compress_right`](http://programming.sirrida.de/bit_perm.html#c_e), Gosper's Hack, and a lot of `expand_right`'s. Unfortunately, `expand_right` is very expensive without hardware support (which is currently only present in Haswell). I'll think about an other way

Comment: Every poker-hand-as-bitmap trick you can imagine has already been done in http://pokersource.sourceforge.net/ , so you might look there for clues (it's in C).  My own https://github.com/lcrocker/ojcardlib library (also in C) is callable from Java, but uses cards-as-ints representation rather than bitmaps.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I got it. I think. I constructed a version of Gosper's Hack for fragmented fields that I'm not entirely sure about, but it worked for this case.

```
static long next(long v, long m)
{
    long t = v | (v - 1 & m);
    long t1 = (((t | ~m) + 1) & m);
    int c = Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(v) + 2; // *
    long w = t1 | (((~t & t1) - 1 & m) >>> c);
    return w;
}
```

I'm not sure why the 2 in the line marked with an asterisk is a 2 instead of a 1.

Anyway, if you do `x = next(x, 0x155)` in a loop (start with `x = 0x15` of course) you get those ten things you listed.

Comment: Thanks harold. I'll try this now... do you have an implementation of "numberOfTrailingZeros"? If not, I'll write one.

Comment: @SteveMcLeod oh sorry, went wrong in the copying. Should be `Long.numberOfTrailingZeros`

Comment: Start with x=0x15? or 0x155?

Comment: Start with x=0x15, the mask is 0x155

Comment: How do I know to start with 0x15? It works, but I don't know why you picked this as the starting value of x

Comment: It is the lowest value from the set, do you want suggestions on how to compute that for a variable mask?

Comment: I'd love suggestions...I wrote something to do it just now, but not being an amateur at bit-fiddling, I'm curious to see a pro do it :)

Comment: You could apply `m &= m - 1` (to remove the rightmost set bit) three times, and then xor the "`m` with three fewer bits set" with the original `m` to get just those three bits. For high or variable counts .. just loop it I guess. `expand_right` would also work, but not really worth it without hardware support, even though it avoids that loop.

Comment: This seems to only work if the mask contains alternating one and zero bits.

Comment: @FalkHüffner the bits don't align properly otherwise. Well it can actually work in a couple of other cases if the +2 is changed back to +1, not many cases though.

Answer (score 2):

I also tried to adapt the standard algorithm for enumerating combinations of a complete set of bits. That algorithm finds the lowest group of 1-bits, moves the highest bit one to the left, and shifts the other ones to the bottom. So for our case, we need to find the k lowest set bits. I didn't have any idea how to do that without a loop, which assumes a fast "popcount" instruction is available (count the number of 1-bits):

```
unsigned next_combination(unsigned comb, unsigned set) {
    unsigned h = (-comb & (comb ^ set)) - 1;
    unsigned l = set;
    for (int i = 0; i < popcount(h & comb) - 1; ++i)
        l &= l - 1;
    comb = (set & h) ^ l;
    return comb;
}
```

**Edit:** I found a different approach that does without the popcount at the chess programming wiki: [Traversing Subsets of a Set](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Traversing+Subsets+of+a+Set). It can be slightly simplified as follows:

```
unsigned next_combination(unsigned comb, unsigned set) {
    unsigned tmp = comb - 1;
    unsigned rip = set & ((tmp | comb) - set);
    for (comb = (tmp ^ rip) & comb; comb; rip ^= tmp, set ^= tmp) {
        tmp = set & -set;
        comb &= comb - 1;
    }
    return rip;
}
```

Since the loop is only executed once on average, this seems to be actually slightly faster on my machine, probably also because of the bad latency of popcount.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few fast solutions.

### Constructing the array

```java
public static final long[] toThreeBitCombinations(long e) {
    //   get lowest 1 bit; turn off that bit;
    final long a = e & -e; e ^= a;
    final long b = e & -e; e ^= b;
    final long c = e & -e; e ^= c;
    final long d = e & -e; e ^= d;

    final long ab = a | b;
    final long ae = a | e;
    final long be = b | e;
    final long cd = c | d;

    return new long[] { cd | e, be | d, ae | d, be | c, ae | c,
                        ab | e, b | cd, a | cd, ab | d, ab | c
                      };
}
```

[This method produces the same output as you expect for your example input](https://ideone.com/RPuVs0#stdout). If you want the array in ascending order instead:

```java
public static final long[] toThreeBitCombinations(long e) {
    //   get lowest 1 bit; turn off that bit;
    final long a = e & -e; e ^= a;
    final long b = e & -e; e ^= b;
    final long c = e & -e; e ^= c;
    final long d = e & -e; e ^= d;

    final long ab = a | b;
    final long ae = a | e;
    final long be = b | e;
    final long cd = c | d;

    return new long[] { ab | c, ab | d, a | cd, b | cd, ab | e,
                        ae | c, be | c, ae | d, be | d, cd | e
                      };
}
```

[As can be seen, the order is reversed](https://ideone.com/FOTJY4#stdout).

We have, for the construction of the entire array:

ALU usage

- 4 `&`
- 14 `|`
- 4 `^`
- 4 unary `-`

Variable memory usage

- Maximum of 10 64-bit `long`s live simultaneously

Method calls

- 1/10 of a call to this method per element

26 ALU instructions, 80 bytes used, and 1 method call for the entire array compare favorably with other solutions presented here. It also doesn't require the extra work of figuring out what combination-of-three-bits value to start those loops with.

### Telling if an element is in the array without needing to construct the array

This is usually slower than constructing a ten-element array and using a linear search on it unless you're trashing arrays pretty quickly after constructing them.

```java
public static final boolean inThreeBitCombinations(final long three, final long five) {
    return ((three & ~five) == 0) && (Long.bitCount(three) == 3);
}
```